# Can python3.6 install crypto on windows

Tags: python

My python version is python3.6.5. I want to install pycrypto,but there is some errors to install it.So did anyone know how to solve the problen. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you have an error and expect help diagnosing it, you must provide the error. You must also provide details about how you obtained the error (code and/or commands), as well as any relevant details about your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pycryptodome](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/blob/master/README.rst) instead.
PyCryptodome is a fork and is even importable with the same name.

> PyCryptodome is a self-contained Python package of low-level
> cryptographic primitives.
>
> It supports Python 2.6 or newer, all Python 3 versions and PyPy.
>
> The installation procedure depends on the package you want the library
> to be in. PyCryptodome can be used as:
>
> an almost drop-in replacement for the old PyCrypto library.
>
> [...]
>
> PyCryptodome is a fork of PyCrypto.

Comment: Thank you for you answer sincerely.